# RVM / Heroku / Gem: lazy symbol binding failed

Tags: ruby, sqlite, heroku, rubygems, rvm

I can't make this work:

```
apaw:x apaw$ heroku db:pull

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _rb_intern2
  Referenced from: /Users/apaw/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.2/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _rb_intern2
  Referenced from: /Users/apaw/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.2/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

I tried different sqlite3 gem version and they all fail the same.

It worked perfectly before i've installed ruby-1.9.3-p385 via rvm

Comment: try: `rvm gemset clean` and install all gems again

Comment: Can you clarify that you are using Heroku Postgres, and not trying to also use sqlite remotely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to do it by unistalling the heroku toolbelt and installing the heroku gem.

Thank you all for hints

Comment: The heroku gem is deprecated, you should use the Toolbelt and pgbackups for these tasks. Your current workflow will break eventually.

Comment: Also, be sure to switch to ruby1.9.2-p290 to do this (as of this writing): [link](https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps/issues/93)

Answer (score 4):

This may not be the answer you want, but I believe it's the answer you need.

First, assuming you're using Heroku Postgres, you really should use Postgres locally to achieve dev/production parity. Parity between your development and deployment environments prevents subtle bugs from being introduced because of differences between your environments. RVM, Bundler, et. al. work to achieve this goal in other areas; I implore you to do so with  your database. In theory, adapters abstract away any differences in backing services (databases, cache systems). In reality, differences between backing services mean that tiny incompatibilities crop up, causing code that worked and passed tests in development or staging to fail in production.

Second, the `db:pull/push`  commands are deprecated, and you should use `pgbackups:capture/restore` instead. See [Importing and Exporting Heroku Postgres Databases with PG Backups](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export) for more. `db:pull` is notoriously bad when dealing with different backends (postgres remote, sqlite3 local). Your errors above are a fine example. While using pgbackups is arguably more steps, it's much safer and reliable, and should be trivial to script.

Comment: This this this. Don't use sqlite locally, don't use db:push/pull.

Answer (score 3):

SQLite is explicitly *not supported* on the platform because the file system is [ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). As soon as you restart your dynos the things your wrote to your sqlite database will disappear. Use [heroku postgres](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql) instead.

If you still wish to do this, you can fork the [ruby buildpack](http://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby) and change it so that the sqlite3 library files are bundled into your application. The documentation for creating custom buildpacks is [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#creating-a-buildpack).

Comment: I do not think it's not supported - it was just not tested on that ruby - someone should open a bug report for that problem

Comment: No I work here, we don't support it, file system access is ephemeral. As soon as you restart your app anything you wrote to your database will disappear. There is no question about whether it is a good solution, it is not.

Comment: I don't believe OP is talking about using SQLite remotely